# How to make responsible table by using grid?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a table that sould be able to change it's rows and columns count on response to resize or just container width
[image: needed result]

[image]
I tried implement it using background of grid-gap but it creates empty red squares if there are not enough elements in a row
https://jsbin.com/patokutara/1/edit?html,output

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
</div>
```

I tried approach with outline+gap+border
but that's not possible to create beautifull border-raius like in an image above

how to implement responsible table using grid?

Table should change rows/columns count on response of it's width

element should sligtly change it's width if there is a free space left in a row

table bould should be border-radius

border should be collapsed

Comment: If this is tabular data then you should use an actual `table` for semantics and accessibility reasons.

Comment: Also, "tables" don't change rows and column counts or they would not be "tables". Please provide images of what this "table" should look like at various widths.

Answer (score 0):

I think this it's not possible to get a full control of inner and outer borders for a responsiveness grid. But you could try this trick where you overlaps items border and grid border for replicate your example.

```css
body{ background-color: black}
        .grid {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
            grid-auto-rows: auto;
            grid-gap: 0px;
            background: black;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 1px solid white;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .grid__item {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__item">something</div>
        <div class="grid__item">else</div>
        <div class="grid__item">here Test</div>
        <div class="grid__item">another Stage</div>
        <div class="grid__item">status</div>
        <div class="grid__item">table</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your exmaple
but unfortunatelly borders are not collapsing and border still exists above of border-radius
is there any way maybe with js or etc

Answer (score 0):

A solution to collapse the borders of the items laying on the grid last row could be using Javascript to dynamically find out which items match that condition and set their `border-bottom: none`.

Here in this demo I also added a `.container` div for the grid, responsible for the outer border having `border-radius` set.

The demo shows several grids having a different number of items inside to demonstrate the correct behaviour of the border collapsing.

Since the container size may change after page load, the action takes place both on the `DOMContentLoaded` event of `document` and the `resize` event of `window`.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", collapseBordersForAllGrids);
window.addEventListener('resize', collapseBordersForAllGrids);

function collapseBordersForAllGrids(){
  const grids = document.querySelectorAll('.grid');
  grids.forEach( grid => collapseBorders(grid) );  
}

function collapseBorders(grid){
  
  let items = Array.from(grid.children);

  // Sets the border bottom for each item in the grid before performing any further action
  items.forEach(item => item.style.borderBottom = 'solid 1px black');

  // Determines what's the offsetTop of the last row,
  // by looking for the highest value among the grid items
  let lastRowOffsetTop = Math.max(...items.map(item => item.offsetTop));  

  // Grabs the items laying on the grid's last row sharing the same offsetTop found before
  let lastRowItems = items.filter(item => item.offsetTop === lastRowOffsetTop);

  //Removes the bottom border from items in the last row
  lastRowItems.forEach(item => item.style.borderBottom = 'none');

}
```

```css
.container {    
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));  
}

.grid__item {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid black;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item">something</div>
    <div class="grid__item">else</div>
    <div class="grid__item">here Test</div>
    <div class="grid__item">another Stage</div>
    <div class="grid__item">status</div>
    <div class="grid__item">another Stage</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item">something</div>
    <div class="grid__item">else</div>    
  </div>
</div>


<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__item">something</div>
    <div class="grid__item">else</div>
    <div class="grid__item">here Test</div>
    <div class="grid__item">another Stage</div>
    <div class="grid__item">status</div>
    <div class="grid__item">another Stage</div>
    <div class="grid__item">....</div>
    <div class="grid__item">....</div>
    <div class="grid__item">....</div>
    <div class="grid__item">....</div>
    <div class="grid__item">....</div>
  </div>
</div>
```